# TimeManager UnsupportedFormatException

Tags: qgis, time, timemanager

I am trying to use time manager to show patterns of movement for tagged wildlife.  I have a GPS point with time and date every two hours.

[image: test data set]

Then, I select the layer with time manager, and select the date and time column (date and t) in the example and confirm the time format mirrors the information layout of the feature.

[image: data and time manager]

I have selected the time frame size to be 2 hours, however, time manager picks up every feature on the same hour even if they are from different dates.  p.s. the same happens if time frame size is changed to date.

[image: result]

I hope the explanation is clear.  Looking forward to your comments/suggestions.  hopefully not missing something blatantly obvious.

Second attempt:

i have updated the attribute field format to reflect date and time format as follows:
[image]

I then add the layer to time manager and add this format to the time format:
[image]

the result is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Data looks fine in the pictures. What is the data source? Can you post some sample data.

Comment: I don't trust %d/%m/%Y formats. I'd convert the data to YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Hi underdark, how would i convert the data? am i right in thinking i should change the time format in the time manager plugin to YYYY-MM-DD? thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Heikki,  the date source is a point shapefile, created from a CSV file which in turn is created from a report generated by a GPS collar.  I will try to get a sample of the data and add this to the post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps have to be in one of the following formats:

`Integer timestamp in seconds after or before the epoch (1970-1-1)
%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f
%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
%Y-%m-%d %H:%M
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
%Y-%m-%d
%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f
%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S
%Y/%m/%d %H:%M
%Y/%m/%d
%H:%M:%S
%H:%M:%S.%f
%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S.%f
%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S
%Y.%m.%d %H:%M
%Y.%m.%d`

https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager